# Are the definition of superfluid order parameter in real space and $k$-space same?

Tags: fermions, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, tight-binding

Considering fermions tight bind model,in real space the superfluid order parameter can be writed as $$\Delta=g\langle c_{i \uparrow}c_{i\downarrow}\rangle$$ In k space, the definetion of orderparameter is $$\Delta=g\sum_k\langle c_{k \uparrow}c_{-k\downarrow}\rangle.$$ Are they same? Could one transform to another?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done the math right now, but yes it should be the same. When you put in the definition of the Fourier transform for c in k space, you should get a delta distribution which gets rid of the sum.

EDIT:
Now that I had another look, I would say that the first definition is "missing" a sum over $i$ (Einstein convention). So the definitions are still technically right, but inconsistent, because either they should both use Einsteins convention or neither one should use it.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I try to  transfrom  the orderparameter from k space to real space.I get the result that is $$\sum_i<c_{i\uparrow} c_{i\downarrow}>$$. could you point out the mistake in my calculation$$c_{k\uparrow}=1/\sqrt{N}\sum_j e^{ikj}$$
$$\sum_ke^{i(j-j')k}=N\delta_{jj'}$$
$$\sum_kc_{k\uparrow} c_{-k\downarrow}=1/N\sum_j\sum_{j'}\sum_kc_{j\uparrow}c_{j\downarrow}e^{i(j-j')k}$$
$$=\sum_jc_{j\uparrow} c_{j\downarrow}$$

Comment: I took another look and updated the answer.